# Can I set up a static IP address through command line in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip

I'm setting up an Apache web server on a virtual Ubuntu server and I'm having trouble finding a clear cut way of knowing whether the LAN ip of my virtual server is static or dynamic.

I found an article that said to look at the /etc/network/interfaces file. The contents of it are in the screenshot. Can someone tell me if my server's IP is static or dynamic, and if it's dynamic how would I go about setting it to be static?

The server does not show up in my router configuration page even though I have  a bridged adapter set in Virtual Box and can access my web server by entering its IP as the URL in a browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your IP address is a dynamic. through DHCP to get the IP address.

You can use terminal with command `ifconfig -a` to get your IP address.

> if it's dynamic how would I go about setting it to be static?

After you get the IP address, you can write it to `ifcfg-eth0`
More information about how set ubuntu network, refer to the [link](https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/install/configure_networking.html).